# overidding Pythons __eq__ method , isistance & eq mothods return false

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to Python from the Java world.

I have written a Python class called "Instance" with 3 properties(attribute, value, and class). I want to override the "**eq**" method & also the "**hash**" method, I'm using the "attribute" & "value" properties used for object comparison. I instantiated two objects with the same values, however they return as not equal.

Code is below , Class Instance:

```
'''Class of type Instance'''
class Instance(object):
    __attribute = None; 
    __value = None;
    __classification = None; 
    #constructor 
    def __init__(self,attribute,value,classification):
        self.attribute = attribute;
        self.value = value;
        self.classification = classification;
    #setters & getters 
    def setAttribute(self,attribute):
        self.attribute = attribute
    def setValue(self,value):
        self.value = value
    def setClassification(self,classification):
        self.classification = classification

    def getAttribute(self):
        return self.Attribute;
    def getValue(self):
        return self.Value
    def getClassification(self):
        return self.Classification

    def __eq__(self, other):
    #if self & other are the same instance & attribute & value equal
        return isinstance(self,other) and (self.attribute == other.attribute) and (self.value  == other.value)

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.attribute, self.value)
```

I'm instantiating in , another Python module called Testing:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass

from Instance import *

instance1 = Instance('sameValue', 1,'Iris-setosa')
instance2 = Instance('sameValue', 1,'Iris-setosa')

if (instance1 is instance2):
    print "equals"
else:
    print "not equals"
```

The program returns: not equals.

Comment: A few side notes: Double-underscore attribute names are almost always a mistake. Class attributes with very similar names to instance attributes are a recipe for confusion. Attribute names are case-sensitive; you can't assign to `self.value` but then `return self.Value`. Finally, the stray semicolons and extra parens left over from C make your code harder to read.

Comment: One more: Having a module named `Instance` with a class named `Instance` is confusing, especially if you're going to do `from Instance import *`. (Yes, `datetime.datetime` and `Queue.Queue` in the stdlib do that… but they also confuse people all the time, and one of them was fixed in 3.0.)

Comment: And one last one: There's almost never a good reason to write `setValue` and `getValue` methods. Just let your callers use your `value` attribute. The reason Java and C++ style recommend getters and setters is for futureproofing—so you can later change your implementation without breaking your interface. But in Python, that's not an issue; if you need to change the implementation, just use `@property` to keep the same interface. The fact that more than half the lines of code in your class, and 3 of the 4 bugs, are in the getters and setters is exactly why you shouldn't use them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first problem is [`isinstance(self, other)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#isinstance) isn't asking whether `self` and `other` are both instances of compatible types, or whether they're the same instance (as your comment says), it's asking whether `self` is an instance of the type `other`. Since `other` isn't even a type, the answer is always false.

You probably wanted `isinstance(self, type(other))`. Or maybe something more complicated, like `isinstance(self, type(other)) or isinstance(other, type(self))`.

Or maybe you don't really want this at all; even for equality testing, duck typing is often a good idea. If `other` has the same attributes as `self`, and also hashes to the same value, is that good enough? The answer may be no… but you definitely should ask the question.

---

Your second problem is a misunderstanding of `is`:

```
if (instance1 is instance2):
    print "equals"
else:
    print "not equals"
```

The whole point of `is` is that it's asking whether these are *the same object*, not whether these two (possibly distinct) objects are equal to each other. For example:

```
>>> a = []
>>> b = []
>>> a == b
True
>>> a is b
False
```

They're both empty lists, so they're *equal* to each other, but they're two *different* empty lists, which is why you can do this:

```
>>> a.append(0)
>>> b
[]
```

And the same is true with your class. Each `Instance` that you create is going to be a different, separate instance—even if they're all equal.

The `__eq__` method that you define customized the `==` operator. There is no way to customize the `is` operator.

Comment: Thanks @abarnert for catching the errors & bad style, just trying to learn Python quickly for this data mining project I have in a few  months.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of "is" versus "==" , thought they were the same, Python growing pains

Comment: @AryanNaim: It's worth reading two different blog posts called "Python Is Not Java" (google and you should find them both). If you're asking "How do I write this Java in Python?" you're going to write bad code; Python is a very bad Java substitute, but a very good very different language.